# Heroku + Rails: How to allow my Users to add their own Custom Domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

All over the internet there are tons of posts about this, but no answers.

In my Rails app running on Heroku, can I allow my Users to add their own Custom Domains automatically?  Does Heroku allow this?

- Are there add-ons to help with this
- By custom domains, I mean adding using their own top-level-domain,
  not Subdomains. E.g., example.com

Comment: Here's a recent blog post on this: http://www.mccartie.com/2016/04/04/letting-users-add-custom-domains-on-heroku.html

Answer (score 6):

Here's one solution to allow this:

1. Set up a wildcard subdomain (for your app's domain) that points to your Heroku app.
2. Allow users to set a custom subdomain.
3. Users can then set up a CNAME (or ALIAS or ANAME, as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)) that points to their custom subdomain on your app.

Comment: I've tried it.  I get a 'No such app' error from Heroku.  It appears the custom domain still needs to be added on Heroku's side.

Comment: @ac360: Mmm, yeah, come to think of it, with Heroku's domain routing that solution isn't workable. I'd wager that having custom top-level domains isn't going to be possible with Heroku, but maybe someone can come up with something better.

Comment: should the CNAME point to example.com or example.herokuapp.com or proxy.herokuapp.com

Comment: @HaykSaakian: For step #3, it would point to the custom subdomain, e.g., `customer.example.com`.

Comment: One issue I just thought of is if the app and customer both have heroku apps, and the customer wants a subdomain on his site to point to a subdomain on your domain. ex: special.customer.com -> customer.example.com when example.com and customer.com both live on heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#domain-precedence. Would this work?

Comment: Should this work? Because here it doesn't. Can you explain better, @mipadi?

Comment: @mipadi Now I'm confused, because I had not seen your comment saying it was impossible to do this with Heroku. I tried to follow your answer, like this: (1) set Heroku app at `xyz.herokuapp.com`; (2) add `*.xyz.com` as a custom domain in Heroku; (3) let my users have their custom subdomains such as `ludwig.xyz.com`; (4) point another domain, such as `ludwig.org` to `ludwig.xyz.com`. All of this and I got a "No such app" from Heroku when accessing `ludwig.org`. Although `ludwig.xyz.com` works.

Comment: But if I add `ludwig.org` manually as a custom domain in Heroku it works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, it's definitely possible - you have to use the Heroku gem within your application and when they add domains you need to make an API call to add their chosen custom domain to your application.

If you want to be able to use SSL it won't work AFAIK because you can only have one SSL addon per app - however, subdomains are easier since you can do a wildcard subdomain and then it's also possible to use a wildcard SSL on your domain without having to involve making API calls and you then don't have to get your clients edit their DNS to point at your application.